# change icon in chrome extension based on site URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to change the icon of a chrome extension based on the page url the user currently is on. The other answers i've found work however break when I run multiple tabs open.

Currently I'm able to achieve the desired functionlaity by doing this:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  chrome.storage.sync.set({color: '#3aa757'}, function() {
    console.log('hello world');
  });

      var rule1 = {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'xxxx.com'},
          })
        ],
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      };

      var rule2 = {
            conditions: [
              new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'xxxx.com'},
              })
            ],
            actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
          };

      var rule3 = {
            conditions: [
              new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'xxxx.com'},
              })
            ],
            actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
          };

      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
          chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule1, rule2, rule3]);
        });
});
```

However, it seems super messy and feel as though there should be an easier way.

If I try to add or logic to the `pageUrl` it will only work for the first conditional statement.

Comment: Simply combine all three rules into one, with multiple conditions.

Comment: You can also use Array#map to produce conditions out of a simple array of host strings.